# cache issue on shopify app

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, page-caching, shopify-template

We are developing an app which will display a button on product details page to perform some actions. We are using product.metaifields for displaying the same based on a condition. So basically the button display toggles depending upon the metafield value.

The issue we are facing is, activate the feature from admin section and then the button will not show up on the user side unless we do a hard refresh on the browser. What happens here is Shopify caches the metafield value so the condition checking will not work. 
Is there any way to remove the page caching while we perform some action on the app?

Answer (score 0):

When you render a page in Shopify, it renders everything including the metafield resource values you may access while rendering. There is no special caching of a metafield value. If you render a metafield "AAA" on a client-facing page, change the metafield using an App or the Admin to be "BBB" there is no signal to the already rendered page to redraw anything.

If you want dynamic behaviour, like rendering a button with a value based on a metafield resource, you will have to either do a callback to an App, get the new contents, and update the DOM, or use a push strategy like WSS:// to keep a channel open to a backend that monitors these things.

So to sum up, your problem is not one of cached data, but instead the fact that you're rendering a non-dynamic value, and expecting your UX to be dynamic.

Comment: That was really helpful.Simply what am really trying to achieve is activate my plugin from backend and display a button based on that in the product details page. What is the best way to go about this without facing the issue I mentioned above?

Comment: Call your App using the App Proxy pattern once the page loads, and then render the button in the DOM where you want... that way you have access to the product metafield value.

Comment: what I am facing at the moment is that am displaying a button based on a product.metafield value 1 and removes it when value is 0.At the moment, when I enable app configuration on backend and the value is 1 it takes a hard refresh (ctrl+f5 or clear cache on browser) to reflect this 1 as metafield value on user side (to be precise on product details page). How can I solve this?

Comment: I told you already. Use an App Proxy to handle a JS callback.